# Lead Conversion in salesforce using apex

Tags: salesforce

Hi i am trying to convert Lead into account and contact but this code convert only into contact and also don't deleted from lead please help.
Thank in advance.

```
public class ConvertLead {
    public ConvertLead()
    {
        System.debug('convert lead called');
        Lead myLead = [SELECT Id FROM Lead WHERE FirstName = 'John'];
        Database.LeadConvert lc = new Database.LeadConvert();
        lc.setLeadId(myLead.id);
        LeadStatus convertStatus = [SELECT Id, MasterLabel FROM LeadStatus WHERE IsConverted=true LIMIT 1];
        lc.setConvertedStatus(convertStatus.MasterLabel);   
        Database.LeadConvertResult lcr = Database.convertLead(lc);
        System.assert(lcr.isSuccess());
        System.debug('converted');

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working fine, I've executed it anonymously from developer console

I have the following lead from default data which has been provided by SF for developer org:

[image]

I've run your code from developer console for lead with name 'Bertha' the result was as following

[image]

So, please check the environment for things which might block conversion